# General formula for decomposition $n^{th}$ power of $V_1$ rep of $SU(2)$

Tags: representation-theory

If $V_n$ is the $n+1$ dimensional irreducible complex rep of $SU(2)$ I'd like to find closed form formula for:

$$ V_1^{\otimes n}$$

Using tensor distributivity over direct sum and Clebsh formula I've computed first couple powers, but I'm clueless how to go from there.

$$ V_1^{\otimes 2} = V_1 \otimes V_1 = V_2 \oplus V_0$$
$$ V_1^{\otimes 3} = V_1 \otimes (V_2 \oplus V_0) = V_3 \oplus V_1 \oplus V_1$$
$$ V_1^{\otimes 4} = V_1 \otimes (V_3 \oplus V_1 \oplus V_1) = V_4 \oplus V_2 \oplus V_2 \oplus V_2 \oplus V_0 \oplus V_0$$

If one presents number of copies of $n^{th}$ irrep in a table this can be summarized in following table:

\begin{matrix} V_0 & V_1 & V_2 & V_3 & V_4 & V_5\\
  & 1\\
  1&&1\\
&2&&1\\
2&&3&&1\\
&5&&4&&1
\end{matrix}

Is there some simple pattern here I fail to see? Is this a well known sequence of integers?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The multiplicity of $V_k$ in $V_1^{\otimes n}$ can be given a pretty nice combinatorial description; I wrote a [blog post](https://qchu.wordpress.com/2010/03/07/walks-on-graphs-and-tensor-products/) about this a long time ago. It's called [Catalan's triangle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Catalan%27s_triangle) (the table here is oriented differently from yours, its diagonals going down and to the left are your rows) and has a fairly nice closed form. It is [A053121](http://oeis.org/A053121) on OEIS.

Comment: Found my table read row-wise on OEIS but didn't see that there is a closed form expression (https://oeis.org/A008313). Thanks for relevant link to that.